# SQL concatenate row by row by date order with in group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, string-aggregation

I am looking for a way to concatenate the rows into a comma separated string.

Example:
[image]

I am looking for result as below where Result Seq column should concatenate the result column row by row values in order of `Inspectiondate` within group of `ProductNumber`, `Purchaseordernumber`.

[image]

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(PRODUCTNUMBER VARCHAR(10),PURCHASEORDERNUMBER 
VARCHAR(11), INSPECTIONDATE date,BOOKINGTYPEDesc varchar(20),RESULT 
VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @table(PRODUCTNUMBER,PURCHASEORDERNUMBER,INSPECTIONDATE,BOOKINGTYPEDesc,RESULT) 
VALUES 
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003270',  '2023-04-27','FirstInspection','Pass'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003270',  '2023-04-29','FirstInspection', 'Fail'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003270',  '2023-05-02','SecondInspection',    'Reject'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003270',  '2023-05-15','FirstInspection', 'Abort'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003270',  '2023-05-20','FirstInspection', 'Pass'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003270',  '2023-05-21','SecondInspection',    'Fail'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-04-27','FirstInspection', 'Pass'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-04-28','FirstInspection', 'Pass'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-04-29','FirstInspection', 'Pass'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-05-01','FirstInspection', 'Fail'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-05-03','Second',  'Fail'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-05-09','FirstInspection', 'Reject'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-05-12','Second',  'Pass'),
('117858-EUC',  '400P0003327',  '2023-05-15','FirstInspection', 'Pass')
```

Any help on the SQL query.

Comment: [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql), [How do I create a comma-separated list using a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query), [Multiple rows to one comma-separated value in Sql Server \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value-in-sql-server), [SQL convert column to comma separated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68860263/sql-convert-column-to-comma-separated-row), etc, etc, etc.

Comment: There are literally 100's of duplicates for this; take your pick.

Comment: @ThomA This one looks different, they don't actually want to aggregate, more of a `STRING_AGG() OVER (ORDER BY ...` which is not available as a window function.

Comment: @Zhorov updated the input data sql

Comment: @mohan are you azure sql database

Comment: You could with a triangular join, @Charlieface , though not ideal.

Comment: @ThomA Very unideal, probably better to use a rCTE, or possibly a bunch of `LAG` functions. Either way, not a dupe of what you mention.

Comment: Yes i use Azure SQL @DileeprajnarayanThumula

Comment: Fyi please don't use images for data - use formatted tabular text

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate a `ResultSeq` column which concatenates the values in the `Result` column, row by row, ordered by `Inspectiondate`, partitioned by `ProductNumber` and `Purchaseordernumber`, then the following approach is an option:

```
SELECT 
   PRODUCTNUMBER, PURCHASEORDERNUMBER, INSPECTIONDATE, RESULT,
   RESULTSEQ = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(RESULT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY INSPECTIONDATE)
      FROM @table 
      WHERE 
         (PRODUCTNUMBER = t.PRODUCTNUMBER) AND
         (PURCHASEORDERNUMBER = t.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER) AND
         (INSPECTIONDATE <= t.INSPECTIONDATE)
   )
FROM @table t
ORDER BY PRODUCTNUMBER, PURCHASEORDERNUMBER, INSPECTIONDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a recursive CTE.

- Begin by selecting the first row for each group. We can do this using `ROW_NUMBER`.
- For each row in the recursive section, get the next "first row" starting from after our current one.

  - We must use `ROW_NUMBER` again because `TOP` is not allowed in a rCTE.
  - The compiler can optimize away the row-numbering into a `TOP`.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      PRODUCTNUMBER, PURCHASEORDERNUMBER, INSPECTIONDATE, BOOKINGTYPEDesc, RESULT,
      ResultSql = CAST(RESULT AS varchar(max))
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCTNUMBER, PURCHASEORDERNUMBER ORDER BY INSPECTIONDATE)
        FROM @table t
    ) t
    WHERE t.rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t.PRODUCTNUMBER, t.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER, t.INSPECTIONDATE, t.BOOKINGTYPEDesc, t.RESULT,
      CONCAT(cte.ResultSql, ', ', t.RESULT)
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT *,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCTNUMBER, PURCHASEORDERNUMBER ORDER BY INSPECTIONDATE)
        FROM @table t
        WHERE t.PRODUCTNUMBER = cte.PRODUCTNUMBER
          AND t.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER = cte.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER
          AND t.INSPECTIONDATE > cte.INSPECTIONDATE
    ) t
    WHERE t.rn = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/54kr8i9O)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs.
with the help of the links you have given,

I have managed to get the output which i am looking for.
SQL Query:

```
SELECT mt.*,
STUFF((  
    SELECT ', ' + Result 
    FROM @table t
    WHERE t.INSPECTIONDATE <= mt.INSPECTIONDATE  and t.PRODUCTNUMBER = mt.PRODUCTNUMBER and t.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER = mt.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER
    and t.BOOKINGTYPEDesc = 'FirstInspection'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Result_Seq
FROM @table mt
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: To prevent XML escaping you need `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)', 1, 2, '')` although you should really just use `STRING_AGG`